# $ \mathbb P[X > 0] \geq \frac{\mathbb E [X]^ 2}{ \mathbb E [X^2]}$ if the mean is positive and finite

Tags: probability, probability-theory, jensen-inequality

> Let $Χ$ be a random variable for witch $0 < E[X] < \infty$. Prove
> that: $ \mathbb P[X > 0] \geq \frac{\mathbb E [X]^ 2}{ \mathbb E 
>  [X^2]}$
>
> Hint: Use the fact that: $(\mathbb{1}_{\{X>0\}}\  \frac{\mathbb E[X^2]}{ \mathbb E [X]}-X)^ 2 \ge 0.$

I think I am missing something here. I tried to prove this by using the argument that since the hint is greater than $0$ and the hint is a random variable, thn its mean should also be greater than $0$ but I was unable to do anything useful. After that I tried to use the fact that if $Y$ is the r.v. of the hint then:

$\mathbb E[Y]^2 \ge 0 $

$ \mathbb E[\mathbb{1}_{\{X>0\}}\  \frac{\mathbb E[X^2]}{ \mathbb E [X]}-X]^2 \ge 0 $

$ (\frac{\mathbb E[X^2]}{ \mathbb E [X]}\mathbb P[X > 0]-\mathbb E [X])^2 \ge 0$

If I could find a way to get rid of the square this would be correct, but I don't think I can. I think I have to use Jensen's inequality somewhere, but I don't know where. Can anyone suggest a different approach?

Comment: [Paley-Zygmund inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Zygmund_inequality).

Comment: Thank you! I did not know this inequality existed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are given the hint that $$\left(\mathbb{1}_{\{X>0\}}\  \frac{\mathbb E[X^2]}{ \mathbb E[X]}-X\right)^2 \ge 0,$$
which implies
$$\mathbb{1}_{\{X>0\}}\  \frac{\mathbb E[X^2]^2}{\mathbb E[X]^2} - 2\mathbb{1}_{\{X>0\}}\  \frac{\mathbb E[X^2]}{ \mathbb E[X]}X + X^2 \geq 0.$$
Taking the expectation, we have
$$\mathbb{P}[X>0]\  \frac{\mathbb E[X^2]^2}{\mathbb E[X]^2} - 2\ \frac{\mathbb E[X^2]}{ \mathbb E[X]}\mathbb E[\mathbb{1}_{\{X>0\}} X] + \mathbb E[X^2] \geq 0.$$
You can notice that
$$\mathbb E[\mathbb{1}_{\{X>0\}} X] \geq \mathbb E[X],$$
and $\mathbb E[X] \geq 0$ from the conditions, so
$$\mathbb{P}[X>0]\  \frac{\mathbb E[X^2]^2}{\mathbb E[X]^2} + \mathbb E[X^2] \geq 2\ \frac{\mathbb E[X^2]}{ \mathbb E[X]}\mathbb E[\mathbb{1}_{\{X>0\}} X] \geq 2\ \mathbb E[X^2].$$
Subtracting $\mathbb E[X^2]$ from both sides and then multiplying both sides by $\mathbb E[X]^2 / \mathbb E[X^2]$ gives
$$\mathbb P[X > 0] \geq \frac{\mathbb E[X]^2}{\mathbb E[X^2]}.$$

Comment: I' m so sorry, I did not get the chance to respond earlier. Thank you so much! I thought about expanding the square first, but I didn't know what to do with $\mathbb E[\mathbb{1}_{\{X>0\}} X]$, as I had not realised that  $\mathbb E[\mathbb{1}_{\{X>0\}} X]\geq \mathbb E[X]$. Excellent explanation, thanks again!

Comment: Thank you @GiorgosMitropoulos, you're very welcome!